# android studio styles.xml cannot servolve symbol

Tags: android-studio, styles, resolve

I made new style in `styles.xml` file and am trying to use it at the `TextView` objects in `activity_main.xml` file but I keep getting `error: cannot resolve flag`. What's wrong? I was trying to make other styles and it's the same error.

Styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#19df19</item>
</style>

<style name="pytanie">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

In main_activity.xml:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="pytanie numer 1"
        android:textStyle="@styles/pytanie"/>
```

Comment: Use it as `style="@style/pytanie"`

Comment: Thank you, I can't belive that was so easy...